# Adding multiple Unity builds into a React Native Project

Tags: android, react-native, unity-game-engine

I was using https://github.com/azesmway/react-native-unity to integrate a single unity export to a react native app but I wanted to add multiple unity builds in the same app as adding mini games. But couldn't understand how to do that with this library?